# CLLocationManagerDelegate -locationManager(_:startMonitoring:) not called when there is no network

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

When I turned on airplane mode on my iPhone,

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion)
```

were not called any more. However, this delegate gets called when I turn off airplane mode.

Is that normal in CLLocationManager? Or my property set wrong.

I have already set all my the properties.

```
lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
    let lm = CLLocationManager()
    lm.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    lm.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
    lm.showsBackgroundLocationIndicator = true
    lm.delegate = self
    lm.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    let authorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    for region in lm.monitoredRegions {
        lm.stopMonitoring(for: region)
    }
    return lm
}()
```

and              `locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)`

Answer (score 1):

Airplane mode turns off the GPS as well, so yes, not receiving location updates and hence `CLLocationManagerDelegate` methods not getting called are expected.

Comment: What if restart device, region of locationManager will work fine?

Comment: @DeanLee exiting airplane mode should solve the issue, there's no need for restarting the device

Comment: Thanks, but I mean user register a region then shut down the device and shut it up, will the region work fine? There is no relationship between these two questions.

Comment: @DeanLee then you should ask a new question if it's completely unrelated to this question and hence answer :)